# show/hide the image thumbnail label when its hover using wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to come up with an output of a thumbnail label when it is hover it will show up and if it's not being hover, it will be hidden. please help me where or what i've been doing wrong. I am using wordpress and i am a beginner in wordpress. Ive made a custom js file for my javascript code for hiding/showing hover.

here is my js importing in functions.php the mycustomjs.js where i've put my js code:

```
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery() {

 wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mycustomjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mycustomjs.js' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

here is the content of mycustomjs.js :

```
$(function() {
   $("span.effect").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").show();
    },function(){
    $(this).find("span").hide();
  });
 });
```

Here is my wordpress code where the span with a class effect i want to hide it when its not being hovered and show it when hovered :

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
            <?php
            if( $projectsBlog->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="top-featured-image">
                <div class="row center-block">
                <?php while ( $projectsBlog->have_posts() ) : $projectsBlog->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box1">
                    <li class="top-featured-image">
                    <span class="effect"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                    </div>
                <?php if($count==2) :
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="row center-block">'; 
                endif; ?>
                </li>
                <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is what i want clearly, for now here is my output of the code:[image: Output of my code]

i want that image hover text shows when it was being hover only and hides when its not being hovered.

Comment: i already answered i similar question,hope that can help too<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39662319/6511655

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(this).find() use $(this).next().show();

Because i guess you want to hide / show that the_post_thumbnail() right?

Comment: But I don't find any class="span" in you html. I am not sure what you want to hode/show. Can you please explain me more?

Comment: thank you for your fast respond sir.. <span class="effect"><?php the_title(); ?></span> .. here sir

Comment: You can hide show the section on it's own hover as you can't get the span hover when it's already hidden! You need to have have hover effect on something else and show/hide your span on that section hover

Comment: Sorry it's typo error. I mean to say that You can hide show the section on it's own hover as you can't get the span hover when it's already hidden!

Comment: Okay, but basically you can't get the hover event on the tag which is hidden. Can you understand this? You can do this by " li:hover span.effect{display:block} " easily.

Comment: can you edit your answer sir, for me to catch it up ? :'( im a beginner

Comment: Add this css:  .top-featured-image > span.effect{display: block;}

Comment: thank you for your answer sir . after adding sir? no changes in my js?

Comment: no js neede after this. just add this css:
`.top-featured-image > span.effect{display: block;}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your JavaScript, try adding this to your style.css:

```
.top-featured-image .effect {
    display: none;
}

.top-featured-image:hover .effect {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you added it to the right file? Make sure to add it to the `style.css` file, not your JS file. Can you make a snippet/JSFiddle so we can help you better?